# Set prices based on WooCommerce Bookings duration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have a scenario where I need to change the total rental price by adjusting the block cost of a booking based on its duration. Booking duration are customer defined blocks of 4 days.

For 4 days (minimum duration) =  base cost + block cost
For 8 days (maximum duration) =  base cost + block cost + (block cost *0.75).

Based on [Change price of product in WooCommerce cart and checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974645/change-price-of-product-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout/44979997#44979997) answer code where I have made some changes. Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_item_price', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $booking_id = $cart_item['booking']['_booking_id'];
        $booking = get_wc_booking( $booking_id );
        $base_cost  = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_wc_booking_cost', true );
        $block_cost = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_wc_booking_block_cost', true );
        if ( $booking ) {
            $duration   = $cart_item['booking']['duration'];        
            if ($duration == 8) {
                $new_price = $base_cost +$block_cost + ($block_cost * 0.75);    //Calculate the new price           
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price ); // Set the new price
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

This works fine but I wonder if there's a way that I can set this permanently using an action such as woocommerce_bookings_pricing_fields so the discounted price gets displayed on the product page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve it by programmatically adding a price range to bookable products:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_booking', 'modify_product_costs', 100, 1 );

function modify_product_costs( $product_id ){
  $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

  // We check that we have a block cost before
  if ( $product->get_block_cost() > 0 ){
    // Set base cost
    $new_booking_cost = ( $product->get_block_cost() * 0.5 ) + 100;

    $product->set_cost( $new_booking_cost ); 
    $product->save(); // Save the product data

    //Adjust cost for 8 days
    $pricing = array(
    array(
    'type' => 'blocks',
    'cost' => 0.875,
    'modifier' => 'times',
    'base_cost' => $new_booking_cost,
    'base_modifier' => 'equals',
    'from' => 2,
    'to' => 2
    )
    );

    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_booking_pricing', $pricing );
 }
}
```

When a product is saved after entering the block cost, it generates the base cost and adds a pricing line to give the desired outcome.

[image]

Inspirations came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501425/get-pricing-data-for-a-bookable-product-with-date-ranges-in-woocommerce), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054170/show-price-in-woocommerce-product-custom-loop), [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233904/how-to-add-date-range-in-woocommerce-with-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326767/set-bookable-product-base-cost-programatically-in-woocommerce-bookings)