# Woocommerce change price by hook (or another way) from "Woocommerce bookings and appointments" plugin by luginhive.com

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

## **General background of my website**

The website rent rooms based on hourly rental.

I use "WooCommerce Bookings And Appointments" plugin for my website.
The plugin URL is https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-booking-and-appointments/

The plugin support Cost Rules and I control prices for all hours.
But I can't find solution for specific scenario.

## **My goal is to add rule that:**

**If** customer choose time between **10PM to 10AM**.

**And** the **minimum** order hours as **bigger then 6 hours**.

**Then** the price will be for **6 hours**.

## **Sample room price**

**Booking Period** set in general setting with **blocks of 30 minutes**.

**Booking costs setting:**
**Minimum price** for 3 hours is 300$ (we use rules for block 1 to 6).

**Base cost of room:** 300$ (the customer can order less then 3 hours but the price will be at least for 3 hours).

**Block cost:** 50$ (start from block number 7).

**Scenario for example:**

if customer order 4 hours from 11PM to 3AM (total blocks: 8) the price will be regular: 400$ (Base cost: 300$ + 100$ [2 blocks of 50$ each])

if customer order 5 hours from 11PM to 4AM (total blocks: 10) the price will be regular: 500$

if customer order 6 hours from 11PM to 5AM (total blocks: 12) the price will be regular: 600$

If customer order 7 hours from 11PM to 6AM (total blocks: 14) the price will be 600$ instead 700$

If customer order 8 hours from 11PM to 7AM (total blocks: 16) the price will be 600$ instead 800$

If customer order 6 hours from **9PM to 3AM** (total blocks: 12) the price will be 600$

If customer order 7 hours from **9PM to 4AM** (total blocks: 14) the price will be 600$ instead 700$

- 9PM to 10PM = 100$
- 10PM to 4AM = 600$

If customer order 8 hours from **9PM to 5AM** (total blocks: 16) the price will be 600$ instead 800$

- 9PM to 10PM = 100$
- 10PM to 5AM = 600$ **(Rule trigger because the order bigger then 6 hours)**

If customer order 14 hours from **9PM to 11AM** (total blocks: 28) the price will be 800$ instead 1400$

- 9PM to 10PM = 100$
- 10PM to 10AM = 600$ **(Rule trigger because the order bigger then 6 hours)**
- 10AM to 11AM = 100$

I tried follow this post [Set prices based on WooCommerce Bookings duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877833/set-prices-based-on-woocommerce-bookings-duration) and make adjustments to my issue without success.

Comment: We can't help you based on a vague "I tried _something_ and it did not work". Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I created snippet and I don't see any change.
Check this [link](https://wordpress-937234-3383198.cloudwaysapps.com/product/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A8-103-10-06-2023/) to live preview

```
<?php
// Calculates price based on selected booking start time and minimum order hours
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cwpai_booking_price_calculation', 10, 1 );
function cwpai_booking_price_calculation( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get start time and minimum order hours
        $start_time = strtotime($_POST['wc_bookings_field_start_date'][0] . ' ' . $_POST['wc_bookings_field_start_time'][0]);
        $minimum_hours = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_minimum_duration', true );

        // Check if start time and minimum order hours meet condition
        if ( date('H:i', $start_time) >= '22:00' && date('H:i', $start_time) <= '10:00' && $minimum_hours >= 6 ) {
            // Calculate maximum cost for 6 hours
            $max_cost = $cart_item['data']->get_price() * 6;

            // Get current cost based on duration
            $duration = WC_Bookings_Cart::calculate_booking_duration( $cart_item['booking'], true, true );
            $current_cost = $duration['cost'];

            // Update cost to maximum cost for 6 hours
            if ( $current_cost > $max_cost ) {
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $max_cost );
            }
        }
    }
}

// Update post meta when product is saved
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'cwpai_update_booking_meta' );
function cwpai_update_booking_meta( $post_id ) {
    // Only run for bookable products
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_booking_type', true ) !== 'booking' ) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Get minimum order hours
    $minimum_hours = isset( $_POST['_minimum_duration'] ) ? absint( $_POST['_minimum_duration'] ) : 0;

    // Update post meta with new booking cost
    if ( $minimum_hours >= 6 ) {
        $max_cost = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', true ) * 6;
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_new_booking_cost', $max_cost );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_new_booking_cost' );
    }
}

// Modify product costs to new booking cost
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'cwpai_modify_product_costs', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'cwpai_modify_product_costs', 10, 2 );
function cwpai_modify_product_costs( $price, $product ) {
    $new_booking_cost = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_new_booking_cost', true );

    if ( $new_booking_cost ) {
        $price = $new_booking_cost;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I miss something :) Check this [link](https://wordpress-937234-3383198.cloudwaysapps.com/product/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A8-103-10-06-2023/) to live preview

```
/**
 * Custom price calculation for WooCommerce Bookings and Appointments plugin.
 */

// Hook into the 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' action
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_booking_price_calculation', 10, 1);
function custom_booking_price_calculation($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    // Get current time
    $current_time = current_time('timestamp');

    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        if ($product->is_type('booking')) {
            $booking_data = $product->get_data();
            $start_time = strtotime($booking_data['date_from']);
            $end_time = strtotime($booking_data['date_to']);
            $selected_blocks = ceil(($end_time - $start_time) / 1800); // 1800 seconds = 30 minutes

            // Condition #1: Start time is between 10:00 PM and 10:00 AM
            $start_hour = date('H', $start_time);
            if ($start_hour >= 22 || $start_hour <= 10) {
                // Condition #2: Minimum order blocks greater than or equal to 12
                if ($selected_blocks >= 12) {
                    // Condition #3: Calculate price for maximum 12 blocks based on rules
                    $base_cost = 300; // Base cost from product settings
                    $cost_per_block = 50; // Cost per block from product settings

                    $max_blocks = min($selected_blocks, 12);
                    $price = $base_cost + ($cost_per_block * $max_blocks);

                    // Set new price for the booking
                    $booking_data['cost'] = $price;
                    $booking = new WC_Booking($booking_data['booking_id']);
                    $booking->set_cost($price);

                    // Update booking data
                    $product->set_props($booking_data);
                    $product->save();

                    // Update cart item data
                    $cart_item['data'] = $product;
                    $cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;

                    // Update cart totals
                    $cart->set_cart_contents_total();
                    $cart->set_cart_contents_tax();
                    $cart->set_total($cart->subtotal + $cart->tax_total, $cart->shipping_total);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Hook into the 'update_post_meta' action
add_action('update_post_meta', 'custom_booking_price_update_post_meta', 10, 3);
function custom_booking_price_update_post_meta($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key) {
    if ($meta_key === '_cost') {
        $booking = new WC_Booking($object_id);
        $booking_data = $booking->get_data();
        $booking_cost = $booking_data['cost'];

        // Update booking cost if necessary
        if ($booking_cost) {
            update_post_meta($object_id, '_cost', $booking_cost);
        }
    }
}

// Hook into the 'new_booking_cost' filter
add_filter('new_booking_cost', 'custom_booking_price_new_booking_cost', 10, 4);
function custom_booking_price_new_booking_cost($cost, $resource_id, $start, $end) {
    // Check if the calculation has already been performed
    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2) {
        return $cost;
    }

    // Calculate the number of blocks
    $selected_blocks = ceil(($end - $start) / 1800);

    // Condition #1: Start time is between 10:00 PM and 10:00 AM
    $start_hour = date('H', $start);
    $start_minute = date('i', $start);
    if (($start_hour == 22 && $start_minute >= 0) || ($start_hour >= 23 || $start_hour <= 9)) {
        // Condition #2: Minimum order blocks greater than or equal to 12
        if ($selected_blocks >= 12) {
            // Condition #3: Calculate price for maximum 12 blocks based on rules
            $base_cost = 300; // Base cost from product settings
            $cost_per_block = 50; // Cost per block from product settings

            $max_blocks = min($selected_blocks, 12);
            $price = $base_cost + ($cost_per_block * $max_blocks);

            return $price;
        }
    }

    return $cost;
}




// Function to modify the base cost of a bookable product
function modify_baseprice($base_cost, $product_id, $booking_id) {
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    if ($product->is_type('booking')) {
        $booking_base_cost = $product->get_meta('_cost');

        if ($booking_base_cost) {
            $booking_base_cost = max(0, (float)$booking_base_cost);
            $product->set_base_cost($booking_base_cost);
            $product->save();
            return $booking_base_cost;
        }
    }

    return $base_cost;
}


// Hook into the 'woocommerce_bookings_after_booking_base_cost' action
add_action('woocommerce_bookings_after_booking_base_cost', 'modify_baseprice', 10, 3);




// Hook into the 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_booking' action
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta_booking', 'modify_bookable_product_base_cost', 100, 1);
function modify_bookable_product_base_cost($product_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['_cost'])) {
        $booking_base_cost = max(0, (float)$_POST['_cost']);
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_base_cost', $booking_base_cost);
    }
}
```